# Blessing or no blessing before counting the Omer?

Tags: blessing, sefirat-ha-omer, embarrassment

When you count the Omer during Maariv, you can say the blessing that precedes the count only if you have not missed a day of counting.  If you missed a day, you can say Amen to the blessing said by others, but may not say it yourself.  This is because of the way the commandment is phrased:

> And from the day on which you bring the sheaf of elevation offering — the day after the sabbath — you shall count off seven weeks. They must be complete: you must count until the day after the seventh week—fifty days. [[Lev. 23:15-16]](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Enforcing this rule may publicly embarrass those who missed a day, because it clearly identifies them.  Embarrassing someone in public is a serious violation.  Practically, how are these two conflicting concerns reconciled?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38108/170

Comment: If someone is truly embarrassed they can pretend to say the bracha and then count, whats the big deal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a chazan who missed a day count the omer with a b'racha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38108/should-a-chazan-who-missed-a-day-count-the-omer-with-a-bracha)

Comment: I reject your premise. Anyone can choose to just say Amen to the Chazzan even if they haven't missed a night. There is no need to say it on your own. Some even recommend that practice for everyone, so it doesn't indicate anything

Comment: @user15464 -- That other question dealt only with a *service leader* who missed a day.  My question deals with Plain Joe in the back row.  I disagree with the notion that the kavod of the rabbi or cantor must be preserved, but that of Plain Joe is expendable.

Comment: @user15464 Maybe it’s the same answer, maybe not. Perhaps the same way we’re concerned for the embarrassment for the Rabbi, we’re concerned for everyone else; perhaps we’re only concerned for the Rabbi because it’s a much larger embarrassment than a random congregant, who can much more easily hide that he missed a day.

Comment: @Maurice no one said the leader is the only person whose feelings matters. He's just the only person who'd reasonably be embarrassed

Comment: Some perspective. People view, stare, gawk - whatever term you wish - at the rabbi because he is the congregation leader and they have high expectations of him. They expect flawlessness. Whether that's a fair expectation or not is debatable, but that's how it is. Not to demean myself, but, no one expects any such standard of me. I think if people are intentionally looking at other congregants to see who has missed the Omer counting - offhand, I don't think anyone cares either way. If they do care, they're a *yachne*, which is **their** fault, not mine.

Comment: Related Shearim Mitzuyanim B'Halacha 120:4 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14619&pgnum=132



From http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21283&st=&pgnum=446